# What's the right way to encrypt a password in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I recently had to encrypt a password to later let it be used in an .sh file by a user.
The way I did it was:

1. Store the encrypted password in an e.g., secret.txt file
2. Create an .sh file where I would decrypt the password and store it in a variable.

Something like this:

```
#bin/bash

USERNAME=adm
var=$(cat secret.txt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 \
 -salt -pass pass:Secret@123#)

tabcmd login -u "$USERNAME" -p "$var"
tabcmd runschedule "PMS Daily 6AM"
```

Here you can see that the password used to decrypt the original String is `Secret@123#`.
That means that the only thing the  user has to do in order to see the real password is to run the script stored in the variable…

I know I might update the user permissions to prevent him from reading that file — unfortunately, the user owns the server in this case.

Is there a better way to do this? My goal would be to prevent the user from knowing the real password in any possible way.

Thank you

-A

Comment: Put the password into some kind of keyring, depending on the OS, and retrieve the password from there. And who do you want to protect / hide the password / the encrypted contents from? If this is on the user's machine what is the point of all this? No, you cannot hide it from a sophisticated user.

Comment: I prefer to use hashing instead. That way it will be "impossible" (very hard) to get the clear text password back even if the file with the passwords is leaked . When a user enters a password, hash it. If the hash becomes the same as the hash you stored, it's ok.

Comment: @luk2302 I agree with you, it's stupid, but I'm trying to solve other's mistakes :). To sum it up — A software was installed on the user's machine, meaning the user has all the rights. In order to log in to that installed software, one needs admin credentials. These credentials cannot be known by the user. In our case, the user wants to refresh some data sources in the software, therefore I created him an .sh file he could run to do the work for him. Nevertheless, that .sh file contains the encrypted admin credentials I have mentioned

Comment: Then no, you have no way to do this securely. The fact that there are admin credentials that the user "cannot know" is already a indication this is poorly designed. Hashing obviously does not work either, that solves an entirely different problem. You cannot remote log into the machine and do it that way since the user may log and monitor all interactions. The user may reverse engineer the application and get admin access anyway. This is futile.

Comment: Whatever you try: you give something to the user to run, the user can modify it to run something different and use the rest of whatever you passed along to run it as an admin.

Comment: `To sum it up — A software was installed` Please do not ask XY questions. It would be way more helpful for you if you would ask "how to encrypt password in my specific case" instead of "What's the right way to encrypt ". There is no "right way" of encrypting, or rather every way that does not give access to any third person is "the right way". `meaning the user has all the rights` Means it is not possible. You have to have something that the user does not have access to.

Comment: @luk2302 I agree with you on all points, just didn't know if there was something I maybe might have not considered. Thx anyway :)